# Problemas al consumir una api localmente con flutter y el emulador de andriod studio

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

estoy teniendo problemas al intentar consumir apis localmente, se que el problema esta entre el emulador y la pc, por lo que llegue a entender del tema, desde postman y el swagger de net core pruebo lo pruebo y me funciona bien, el quilombo lo tengo cuando pruebo desde el emulador de andriod studio me tira bad request error 400, en algunos foros vi que recomiendan poner la ip del emulador del andriod cambiandola desde configuraciones en el proxy, poner la ip de mi maquina y el puerto en el que uso las api, agradezco si me podrian ayudar,

Aqui es donde hago la peticion post  a la api  que esta en localhost

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String passowrd) async {
final Map map = {
  'username': email,
  'password': passowrd,
};
print(map);

final resp = await http.post(
  'https://10.0.2.2:44394/api/User/authenticate',
  body: json.encode(map),
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
);
print(resp.body);
Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);
print(decodedResp);
if (decodedResp.containsKey('token')) {
  _prefs.token = decodedResp['token'];

  return {'ok': true, 'token': decodedResp['token']};
} else {
  return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': decodedResp['error']['message']};
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intente y no me resulto

1)Poner mi ip en la peticion http

2)Poner la ip del emulador del andriod studio que es 10.0.2.2 en el http

3)En la url sacar el HTTPS completo

4)Dejando solo http

5)cambiar la ip del andriod studio por la de mi maquina y usar el mismo puerto que la api

6)cambiar la ip del emulador por otra dentro del rango 10.0.1.225

7)la api esta probada desde el Swagger de net core y desde Postman y funciona correctamente

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomiendo cambiar tus imagenes por codigo, para que se pueda copiar mejor y replicar tu error. Tambien te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular tus preguntas mejor.

Comment: Hola Edgar, muchas gracias por tus recomendaciones, ahora supongo si deberia estar un poco mejor

Comment: Has revisado si están habilitadas las CORS en tu backend, es un problema común.

Comment: Dav no no lo tiene habilitado por lo que google y vi en el proyecto, pero sigo sin ver la relacion entre mi problema y esto, soy dentro de todo nuevo en la programacion, te agradezco si me explicas un poco mas al detalle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar descargando el adb de andriod studio developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools tirando el siguiente comando adb reverse tcp:tcp:TUPUERTO tcp:TUPUERTO en cmd